# IPAddress.MapToIPv6 for.NET 4?

Tags: c#, sockets, ip

I want to convert my `IPv4Address` into `IPv6Address` and `IPAddress.MapToIPv6` is only for .`NET 4.5`

Any solution for .NET 4 ?

Comment: You could always [copy the implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,720).

Answer (score 0):

An IPv4 address is translated to an IPv6 address by placing the 4 octets of
the IPv4 address into the rightmost 4 octets of the IPv6 address.

Full method [here](http://www.nish.com/2009/11/convert-ipv4-into-ipv6/)

Ex: 192.168.25.234 -> C0A8:19EA

Comment: IPv6 address is longer so how can i complete the relevant values that missing ? i have method that create ipv6 address from string or uint128 value

Comment: Set the remaining left-most octets to 0.

Comment: Be careful. That creates an **IPv4-compatible IPv6 address**, which is only suitable if the target device supports both IPv4 and IPv6. If it only supports IPv4, then use an **IPv4-mapped IPv6 address** instead. Read this: [IPv6/IPv4 Address Embedding](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_IPv6IPv4AddressEmbedding-2.htm)