# Convert IPv4 to IPv6 manually

Tags: .net, sockets, converters, ipv6, ipv4

After read [this](http://www.nish.com/2009/11/convert-ipv4-into-ipv6/) article i have a question:

In the exapmle in this link there is explanation hot to convert `192.168.25.234` into equivalent `IPv6 address` so in the example this address become `C0A8:19EA` and it says that this can be written into the following 128-Bit IPv6 link-local address:

```
FE80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:C0A8:19EA
```

or

```
FE80::C0A8:19EA
```

So my question is how `C0A8:19EA` become `FE80:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:C0A8:19EA` ?

Comment: What's the difference with your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902191/ipaddress-maptoipv6-for-net-4)?

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are different protocols. There are special circumstances where an IPv4 address is used inside an IPv6 address. But remember that these are special circumstances: normally IPv4 and IPv6 are completely separate with different addresses. Don't expect that you can derive one from the other.

Comment: The case that ipv4 is used inside ipv6 is tunneling ? i saw pcap file with both ipv4 and ipv6 layers in the same packet

Comment: There are tunnelling mechanisms (such as 6to4) that use the IPv4 address as part of the IPv6 address, but those are special cases. Usually the inner and outer addresses are unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C0, A8, 19 and EA are just 192, 168, 25 and 234 displayed in hex. The `FE80` is a well-known prefix for link local. The rest is always all zero in this case (or for the terse form: can be omitted). Concatenate: job done.